# R: How to measure difference with both categorical and numeric features

Tags: r, data-processing

I'm very new to data wrangling. And now I have this problem at hand:

So basically I have used tables of biochemical measurements (all numerical) of patients to perform cluster analysis, and by doing so I sorted them into 5 clusters.

Then I also have their clinical data/features, now I want to ask if any of these clinical features (a mix of numerical and categorical features) are significantly different from one cluster to another. So how can I go about this? What test shall I perform? Is there a good library I should be looking at?

To give you an idea about the "clinical data":

```
ClusterAssigned  PatientID  age sex stage FISH      IGHV        IgG ...
      1          S134567    50  m   4     11q       mutated     scig
      1          S234667    80  m   2     13q       mutated     6.5
      1          S135677    55  f   4     11q       na          scig
      1          S356576    94  f   2     13q,t12   unmutated   5
      1          S187978    59  m   4     11q       mutated     scig
      4          S278967    80  f   2     17q       unmutated   6.5
      4          S123467    75  f   4     na        unmutated   9.1
      4          S234577    62  m   2     t12       mutated     9
  .....
```

So you see the Cluster assigned is based on my cluster analysis. FISH, IGHV, IgG are categorical, and you can see there are sometimes na values and sometimes one person can have multiple entry "13q,t12".

In a discounted way, I can perhaps just take cluster 1 and 4 patients out, emit all na ones, and ask if there is a difference in their age, sex, FISH, IGHV...Still what's the method I can use here to perform such test in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the categorical variables into dummy variables first and then perform a normal cluster analysis.

Things get more complicated if you have ordered categorical fields

Comment: Thank you @Alistair, I will have a crack on them. I don't think any of them are ordered at this stage.